# I have a mod security error when try to deply wordpress on iis

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, mod-security2

I have iis on my machine and I want to add to it my wordpress website

I have moved my website to

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite

and install my database on mysql server

and then create website in iis that point to this folder after I have installed wep platform and install php for iis

and add binding to my website on port 81

when I was using localhost:81 the wordpress admin worked but the website itself show an empty screen

when I change the siteurl to 127.0.0.1:81 both admin and website are not working and show the following error

[image]

Comment: Did you grant the IUSR account full access to the website directory? Please refer to the below steps for hosting the Wordexpress website in IIS.
https://zaven.co/blog/install-wordpress-iis/

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign Port 81 to IIS. Default PORT for unencrypted networks is 80. For admin Panel, try localhost/wp-admin or 127.0.0.1/wp-admin or Try Router IP address assigned.

Both PHP errors and database errors can manifest as a white screen, a blank screen with no information, commonly known in the WordPress community as the WordPress White Screen of Death (WSOD).

If your database cannot be connected, search for wp-config.php and change Database Username and Pass.
Also, If you still cannot install, start an FTP connection with Home directory of Wordpress and try Softaculous FTP installer,

Comment: Ok, I just saw your Image and this is problem with ModSecurity error. Try Disabling Firewall or ModSecurity. This could also happen if your server is not properly configured and Try to Display Index(No Intexing enabled in IIS) Try disabling no indexing and then try if Directory view is there